# CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY is executed but the CONCURRENTLY option lost after creation?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, ddl, postgresql-14

In my Postgres 14.3 database on AWS RDS, I want to create an index without blocking other database operations. So I want to use the `CONCURRENTLY` option and I executed the following statement successfully.

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_test
    ON public.ap_identifier USING btree (cluster_id);
```

But when checking the database with:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE indexname = 'idx_test';
```

I only see: [Index without `CONCURRENTLY` option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7dPr.png)

I am expecting the index is created with `CONCURRENTLY` option.

Is there any database switch to turn this feature on, or why does it seem to ignore `CONCURRENTLY`?

Comment: CONCURRENTLY is an option to the CREATE INDEX command, it is not an option of the index itself.  Once the index is (successfully) built, it doesn't remember/care if it were built concurrently, nor under a full moon.

Comment: There is no such thing as a concurrent index. The `CONCURRENTLY` option only states that the index is to be created concurrently. So, is not an index property but rather a creation option to avoid locks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As has been commented, `CONCURRENTLY` is not a property of the index, but an instruction to create the index without blocking concurrent writes. The resulting index does not remember that option in any way. Read the chapter ["Building Indexes Concurrently"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY) in the manual.

Creating indexes on big tables can take a while. The system table
[`pg_stat_progress_create_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/progress-reporting.html#CREATE-INDEX-PROGRESS-REPORTING) can be queried for progress reporting. While that is going on, `CONCURRENTLY` is still reflected in the `command` column.

To your consolation: once created, all indexes are "concurrent" anyway, in the sense that they are maintained automatically without blocking concurrent reads or writes (except for `UNIQUE` indexes that prevent duplicates.)

Comment: What you might see is that the index is "invalid" while it is still being built, or if it fails.